# How can I "catch" first visit of specific user today?

Tags: 7

I have to know when specific user start to visit site every day.
I need server solution (cookie files are unsuitable).
What hook can be useful?

UPDATE
Possible solution:
Create date field for user. Fill with cron at midnight the field with user `access` value. Compare the field with current visit time.

Comment: Authenticated or anonymous users? For robust tracking solutions that drill down to individual users it maybe worth looking at something like [Kissmetrics](https://www.kissmetrics.com/). (Although this could be overkill for what your trying)

Comment: When you say "catch" do you mean record each day's first visit in the database (retain history for each day), or just know which was the latest day's first visit (no history)?